# Digital Piano/Electronic Keyboard replacement key

Tags: piano, keyboard, repair

I completely snapped one of the unweighted keys on my digital piano/keyboard. After a bit of searching on the internet, I can't find where I might order a replacement key to switch the broken one out with. If anyone has a lead please let me know!

Comment: Buying advice is not available on StackExchange, and we'd have needed more information about the keyboard anyway. However; visit https://www.syntaur.com/; that's the only place I know that could conceivably have spares on the shelf.

Comment: Superglue usually works. Otherwise swap for a matching key from one end.

Comment: @Tim Gluing is always an option however I would recommend a small test on the back to be sure that SG does not dissolve this plastic!